# Passing data from Unity3D to C++ dll and vice versa

Tags: c++, opencv, unity-game-engine, marshalling, augmented-reality

I'm currently working on my thesis (MSc Computer Science) which is an Augmented Reality project using OpenCV C++ integrated with Unity3D (for the rendering part). In order to integrate OpenCV with Unity3D I exported the OpenCV (c++) code as a dll and then I am importing that dll in Unity3D for accessing the dll's methods etc.. In addition the University gave me some money to buy OpenCV for Unity (it is implemented in C# using OpenCV for Java) and I am using it as well in Unity3D. The problem is that, it does not support SURF feature extractor and that's why I am not implementing my C++ code straightforward into C# using that asset.

So I want to pass a frame (Mat) from Unity3D (C#) to the C++ dll, then do some calculations and after that return some Mat objects, for example the rotation matrix,translation vector and the camera pose. The most important thing is that I don't know how to pass the Mat frame from Unity3D to the C++ dll.

Can anyone explain to me how to achieve this and also can you post a sample code ?

**EDIT:** The Unity3D asset that I am using can be found here : [OpenCV for Unity3D](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/21088)

Comment: yes I am using that asset you mentioned. I will edit my post and include it. I thought I wasn't allowed to post external links. thanks

Comment: The sad thing is that SIFT and SURF are not implemented on that asset. That's why I implemented my code in C++ where SIFT and SURF are available and then I am importing the dll to Unity3D

Comment: yes, I am able to integrate the C++ dll with Unity, I can call simple methods like adding two numbers and getting back the result, but the main point of the question was how to pass an image (Mat type) from Unity to the C++ dll then the algorithm will do some calculation and return them back to Unity.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but most of the people here when got their answers never post the solution to everyone. I found 2 similar posts here..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found the solution (ohh yeahhhhhhhh) :)

First of all, I needed to convert my C# Mat (frame) into an array of bytes. Then I created a pointer in order to point at the array of bytes address (which is the image data). After this I invoked the C++ dll method and passed the pointer as an argument (and also the width and height of image). Finally in the C++ dll I reconstructed the C++ Mat using the array of bytes from C#.

Code in Unity3D(C#):

```
        //frame is the C# Mat and byte_array our array of byes

        //to initialize the size of our byte array (image pixels * channels)
        byte_array= new byte[frame.cols () * frame.rows () * frame.channels ()];
        //copy the frame data to our array
        Utils.copyFromMat (frame,byte_array);
        //initialize a pointer with the apropriate size (array size)
        IntPtr pointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(byte_array.Length);
        Marshal.Copy (byte_array, 0, pointer , byte_array.Length);
        //here i call the C++ method (I imported a C++ dll)
        myCplusplusMethod(pointer ,frame.height(),frame.width());
        //free the pointer
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pointer );
```

Now in order to reconstruct the image in C++ using the passed data from C#:

```
void myCplusplusMethod(unsigned char* data,int height,int width){
     //btw you have to get the correct type. In my situation I use debug from C# and I found out that my image is CV_8UC3 type.
     Mat constructed= Mat(height, width, CV_8UC3, data);
     //..do whatever using the image.. (calculations , etc)..
}
```

Comment: Nice work.  Good for posting it here.  Dude that's what I suggested using a byte array.  You can "tick" your own answer, it's cool.